# Calling Static Method And Passing Model To Controller

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am just trying to pass my form to my controller and I'm getting this error no matter what I try:

```
render(play.api.data.Form<models.Service>) in 'null' cannot be applied to (play.data.Form<models.Service)
```

**Error Line:**

```
return ok(info.render(sServiceForm));
```

**Info.scale.html - View**

```
@(serviceForm : Form[Service])
@import helper._

@main("Service info") {
  <h1>Service Information</h1>
  @helper.form(action = routes.Services.save()) {
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Service</legend>
      @helper.inputText(serviceForm.field("code"), '_label -> "Code")
      @helper.inputText(serviceForm.field("description"), '_label -> "Description")
      @helper.inputText(serviceForm.field("description"), '_label -> "Description")
    </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  }
}
```

**Service.java - Model**

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by James on 3/4/2016.
 */
// Telling play framework that this is a class thats going to map as a model to save service records
@Entity
public class Service extends Model {
    // Internal ID to reference a certain activity
    @Id
    public String code;
    public String description;
}
```

**Services.java - Controller**

```
package controllers;

import models.Service;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.data.Form;
import views.html.services.info;

/**
 * Created by James on 3/4/2016.
 */
public class Services extends Controller {
    // Creating static class variable, calling static method and passing our model class.
    //private static final Form<Service> sServiceForm = Form.form(Service.class);
   private static final Form<Service> sServiceForm = play.data.Form.form(Service.class);
    public Result list() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public Result addService() {
        return ok(info.render(sServiceForm));
    }

    public Result save()
    {
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

If I comment out:

```
private static final Form<Service> sServiceForm = Form.form(Service.class);
```

And change my `addService` to `return TODO;` the site compiles fine and I can go throughout it fine. This line breaks the site even if I am still returning TODO:

```
private static final Form<Service> sServiceForm = Form.form(Service.class);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? At IDEA or in your console? I suppose this is just an IDEA "problem" by not recognizing the implicit conversion between `play.data.Form` (Java form version, at your controller) and `play.api.data.Form` (Scala, at your view). A possible way to make IDEA happy is declare your view like `@(serviceForm : play.data.Form[Service])`. Also, if you are already using Play 2.5.0, inject a `FormFactory` instead of using the deprecated `Form.form`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want it to work using FormFactory.
You can follow this code. 
Someone from gitter helped me. 
So, credits for him actually.

Here's my code:

Services.java

```
package controllers;

import models.Service;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.services.info;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Services extends Controller {
    private final Form<Service> serviceForm;

    @Inject
    public Services(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.serviceForm =  formFactory.form(Service.class);
    }

    public Result list() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public Result addService() {
        return ok(info.render(serviceForm));
    }

    public Result save() {
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

and info.scala.html

```
@(serviceForm : play.data.Form[Service])
@import helper._
@main("Service info"){

  <h1>Service Information</h1>

  @form(action = routes.Services.save()) {

    <fieldset>

      <legend>Service</legend>
      @inputText(serviceForm("code"), '_label -> "Code")
      @inputText(serviceForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")
      @inputText(serviceForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")

    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>

  }

}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11699871)

Comment: i already edit it. This time, answering the question i've encountered